# author information google api

Tags: json, google-books

1) I would like to obtain "About author" information from Google API but the normal query does not return that info in the JSON reply.

2) The  HTML link in JSON reply gives more information than in the JSON file (for eg: categories).  Isn't everything supposed to be in the JSON file itself so that we can deserialize from it directly?

Any suggestions please?  Thanks

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but doing VB.NET